# How to tackle the given autocorrelation problem

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

If $X(t)$ is a WSS process with autocorrelation function $R_{xx}(T)$ and $Y(t) = X(t+a) - X(t)$, Show that $$R_{yy}(T) = 2R_{xx}(T) - R_{xx}(T + 2a) - R_{xx}(T + 2a).$$

Comment: It doesn't seem right. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I'm getting $R_{yy}(T) = 2R_{xx}(T)-R_{xx}(T+a)-R_{xx}(T-a)$. @msm does that look better?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the correct equation @JimmyK4542.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
R_{yy}(\tau)&=\mathsf{E}\{y(t)y(t+\tau)\}\\
&=\mathsf{E}\{[x(t+a)-x(t)][x(t+\tau+a)-x(t+\tau)]\}\\
&=\mathsf{E}\{x(t+a)x(t+\tau+a)-x(t+a)x(t+\tau)-x(t)x(t+\tau+a)+x(t)x(t+\tau)]\}\\
&=R_{xx}(\tau)-R_{xx}(\tau-a)-R_{xx}(\tau+a)+R_{xx}(\tau)\\
&=2R_{xx}(\tau)-R_{xx}(\tau-a)-R_{xx}(\tau+a)
\end{align}$$

Comment: The $+$ sign in the last line should be a $-$ sign. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: Thanks @JimmyK4542 fixed it.

Comment: How is E{x(t+a)x(t+τ+a)} = Rxx(τ) ?

Comment: Assume $t_1=t+a$. Then it is equal to $\mathsf{E}\{x(t_1)x(t_1+\tau)\}$, which is equal to $R_{xx}(\tau)$ given that $x(t)$ is WSS.